# I am trying to add some data using Shared Preference but after using shared preference in my code my app has stopped working

Tags: java, android, set, sharedpreferences, logcat

***This is the java code. After adding the part of the shared preference in my code my app has stopped working. Can someone help me out***

```
Button bt, dt, cp, adta;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
Set<String> hash_Set = new HashSet<String>();
String name;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.logout);
    dt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.delete);
    cp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.changepassword);
    adta = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addtask);
    adta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            hash_Set.add("Geeks");
            hash_Set.add("For");
            hash_Set.add("Geeks");
            hash_Set.add("Example");
            hash_Set.add("Set");
            editor.putStringSet("set",hash_Set);
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("set", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Set<String> fetch = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("set", null);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(fetch);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new ProgrammingAdapter((String[]) list.toArray()));
```

***Here is the Log Cat***

2019-09-29 14:09:40.870 5801-5801/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2019-09-29 14:09:40.884 5801-5801/? D/TidaProvider: TidaProvider()
2019-09-29 14:09:40.903 5801-5801/? W/ReflectionUtils: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.os.MessageQueue#enableMonitor()#bestmatch
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethodBestMatch(ReflectionUtils.java:338)
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethodBestMatch(ReflectionUtils.java:375)
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.callMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:800)
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.tryCallMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:818)
        at android.os.BaseLooper.enableMonitor(BaseLooper.java:47)
        at android.os.Looper.prepareMainLooper(Looper.java:112)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
2019-09-29 14:09:40.905 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@f936ca6
2019-09-29 14:09:40.990 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.startup1-1/lib/arm64
2019-09-29 14:09:40.992 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000000
2019-09-29 14:09:41.059 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 W/ComponentDiscovery: Application info not found.
2019-09-29 14:09:41.059 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 W/ComponentDiscovery: Could not retrieve metadata, returning empty list of registrars.
2019-09-29 14:09:41.145 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
2019-09-29 14:09:41.150 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
2019-09-29 14:09:41.152 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2019-09-29 14:09:41.177 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000000
2019-09-29 14:09:41.191 5801-5834/com.example.startup1 V/FA: Cancelling job. JobID: -191561759
2019-09-29 14:09:41.197 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
2019-09-29 14:09:41.203 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 V/FA: onActivityCreated
2019-09-29 14:09:41.222 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 D/AccessibilityManager: current package=com.example.startup1, accessibility manager mIsFinalEnabled=false, mOptimizeEnabled=false, mIsUiAutomationEnabled=false, mIsInterestedPackage=false
2019-09-29 14:09:41.253 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
2019-09-29 14:09:41.253 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2421)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.253 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:779)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.253 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.253 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:161)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void com.example.startup1.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:32)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6868)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1119)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2676)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2784)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1523)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:163)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6238)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:904)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:794)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.startup1-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.startup1-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2421)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:779)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:161)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void com.example.startup1.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:32)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6868)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1119)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2676)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2784)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1523)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:163)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6238)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:904)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.254 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:794)
2019-09-29 14:09:41.346 5801-5834/com.example.startup1 V/FA: Collection enabled
2019-09-29 14:09:41.346 5801-5834/com.example.startup1 V/FA: App package, google app id: com.example.startup1, 1:271808401016:android:306b8c305ec84e4b5e278d
2019-09-29 14:09:41.347 5801-5834/com.example.startup1 I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 12451
2019-09-29 14:09:41.347 5801-5834/com.example.startup1 I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2019-09-29 14:09:41.347 5801-5834/com.example.startup1 I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.startup1
2019-09-29 14:09:41.348 5801-5834/com.example.startup1 D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
2019-09-29 14:09:41.385 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:50084674 intent:Intent { cmp=com.example.startup1/.home }
2019-09-29 14:09:41.501 5801-5834/com.example.startup1 V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2019-09-29 14:09:41.533 5801-5834/com.example.startup1 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2019-09-29 14:09:41.535 5801-5834/com.example.startup1 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2019-09-29 14:09:41.536 5801-5834/com.example.startup1 V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 76758760
2019-09-29 14:09:41.538 5801-5834/com.example.startup1 V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 108
2019-09-29 14:09:41.538 5801-5834/com.example.startup1 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2019-09-29 14:09:41.538 5801-5834/com.example.startup1 V/FA: Activity paused, time: 76758828
2019-09-29 14:09:41.545 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 V/FA: onActivityCreated
2019-09-29 14:09:41.548 5801-5834/com.example.startup1 I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
2019-09-29 14:09:41.555 5801-5834/com.example.startup1 D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=8947373271963293270}]
2019-09-29 14:09:41.586 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@9dd9dd3
2019-09-29 14:09:41.586 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@da4ad10
2019-09-29 14:09:41.593 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-09-29 14:09:41.594 5801-5801/com.example.startup1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.startup1, PID: 5801
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.startup1/com.example.startup1.home}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2784)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1523)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object reference
        at java.util.ArrayList.(ArrayList.java:171)
        at com.example.startup1.home.onCreate(home.java:63)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6868)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2676)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2784) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1523) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794) 
2019-09-29 14:09:41.615 5801-5834/com.example.startup1 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress

Comment: can you post you log?

Comment: yes i have posted

Comment: your list.toArray() is null becz your pass to adapter before to set any values